# Using JaSpell with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to use JaSpell library as a spellchecker for an app. I am having trouble using it with the Eclipse IDE. I created a new Java Project and imported all the files from this [link](http://jaspell.sourceforge.net/) using **File System**. Everything seemed to be working fine until I tried using one of the constructors. I have tried to search online for a tutorial on JaSpell and I have been search through the [javadocs](http://jaspell.sourceforge.net/javadocs/) but I am completely stuck.

[image: This is a picture of the setup that I have on my Eclipse IDE]

Comment: (since your question on Programmers got closed I could not post there): The json object returned by the API is structured differently from what you expect (you could see this with `console.log(json)`. You would need to do something like `var weatherID = json.list[0].weather[0].description;` to get the data you want. (Also I had to activate jQuery inclusion first for CodePen) Result: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwqYEo

Comment: @thorstenmüller Thank you.I really appreciate this. I've been trying to figure out what I did wrong for two weeks now.

Comment: @thorstenmüller why is the structure json.list instead of json.weather?

Comment: I don't know what the API developers reasons are (and if it's properly documented). But if I output the json object in the console of Google Chrome it is easy enough to inspect the data structure. You get a tree view where you can open the sub elements and arrays are marked with the number of elements. On top level there is a city element (sub elements like name, country, coord) and a list element (Array with 40 elements). If I open list I find a datetime (each entry seems for a time slice of 3 hours) and several other objects.

Comment: There are `main` with (grnd_level, humidity, pressure, temp...), weather (description, icon, main...), wind (deg, speed) and a few more. So even without the API documentation a lot of the data is human readable. I guess with the proper docs you could do some rather complete waether prognostics. So it's all about using your browser tools which gets you already quite far. I am not 100% sure how this would look in other browsers but Chromes console window is really powerful. Firefox is similar. In both cases Ctrl-Shift-I in case you didn't know that yet.

Comment: Ohh I see now.  Thank you for all of your help.